# Maxima: How to get the derivative with respect to a vector or matrix?

Tags: maxima, calculus

Is there a way tell maxima that a variable is a vector or matrix (of *N* / *N* x *N* of dimensions), so I get the correct results from `diff`?

I figured `declare` should to this, but it doesn't make a difference:

```
declare(v, nonscalar);
diff(2*v, v);
```

Output:

```
2
```

Expected:

```
2 <some symbol for I>
```

Not to mention, that the answer should be different, if `v` is a vector, or a matrix.